# Alfresco 6/7: externalizing webscript and form files out ot the jar

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm developing custom modules on Alfresco CE 6/7, but still producing amp artifacts.

I've noticed that some files, for examples all the repository webscripts (acs javascript side) and forms configuration (xml files on share) aren't present in the final amp package, as it happens on Alfresco 5, but now they are inside the jar.

Previously, you could edit those files directly on the server (inside the exploded webapp) and then refresh the webscript to hotswap code directly and see the modified behaviour. Now this thing is no more possibile causing the development process to be significantly slower.

Is there a way to change the amp/jar structure to restore the previous behaviour?
Does anybody know why this SDK/Framework decision? Why the refresh webscript pages is still present?

I've searched many and many times for this, but I've not come to any solution yet. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting all the artefacts into jars into the amp/war is just a build/deployment decision to handle the dependencies. This can't be changed easily but there are still options to develop / modify and test webscripts on a running system

- store your repo websripts in the repo data dictionary
- store your webscripts on the server

  - repo webscripts in `shared/classes/alfresco/extension`
  - share webscripts in `shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension`
- configure your development environment for [hot reloading](https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/latest/develop/sdk/#hot-reloading)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, So basically If I put a webscript inside a jar and then a modified version in /shared/classes/alfresco/extension I have my code modified at runtime, just refreshing the webscript from the appropriate URL. 
Is that the same for the xml forms?